# Struts 2 jQuery customising Grid ADD

Tags: struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

Is it possible to customize the values which is getting populated in clicking Add/Edit button?

Comment: can you elaborate more regarding which value you are referring to? are you speaking about values which are shown in jQuery dialog widget or labels of Add/Edit button?

Comment: If i have two columns as below inside a grid  <sjg:gridColumn name="location" index="location" title="Location"
   editable="true" edittype="text" editable="true" hidden="true" />
  <sjg:gridColumn name="metric" index="metric" title="Metric"
   editable="true" edittype="text" editable="true" hidden="true" /> and if i have to display one colum n at the center of page and the other at the right of the page,how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your comment that either you want to change width of column or alignment of text. both the things you can do by using various attributes of `sjg:gridColumn` tags attributes such as **width** and **align** for your reference visit [*this Wiki*](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridColumnTag) which has details about attributes as well as it's usage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i need to arrange the textfields,select type in the popup on cliking add/edit

Comment: if you don't share your code or any further info i am not sure how  i can help you with that!